# how to insert 0001 year in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

how to insert 0001 year in oracle ?

I've tried

```
UPDATE table1
SET 
datblock = to_timestamp('01/01/0001 00:00:00,000000000','DD/MM/RR HH24:MI:SSXFF')
```

but it shows as 2001, anyone can help ?

Comment: Use `YYYY` format instead of `RR`

Comment: Your query works [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=dc76cc90ce7ccc447aa4206b18ccd928).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a timestamp literal:

```sql
UPDATE table1
SET 
datblock = TIMESTAMP '0001-01-01 00:00:00';
```

---

However, your query works as the [string-to-date conversion rules](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-5B755E80-3CB2-4901-BBCF-F0FC764E0BB5) mean that `RR` also matches `RRRR`.

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 (datblock) AS
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2021-09-27 01:23:45' FROM DUAL;

ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SSXFF';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ',.';

UPDATE table1
SET datblock = to_timestamp(
                 '01/01/0001 00:00:00,000000000',
                 'DD/MM/RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'
               );

SELECT * FROM table1;
```

Outputs:

> | DATBLOCK |
> | --- |
> | 0001-01-01 00:00:00,000000000 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=dc76cc90ce7ccc447aa4206b18ccd928)*

Answer (score 5):

Do not use the `RR` format which has a [special logik](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-6C75461E-2E18-4C35-9EB4-038A7E1C9C1F) to decide the century.

Use explicite `YYYY` format

```
select to_timestamp('01/01/0001 00:00:00,000000000','DD/MM/RR HH24:MI:SSXFF') yyyy from dual;

YYYY                         
-----------------------------
01.01.0001 00:00:00,000000000
```